# How to visible or invisible the xml items(text view, image view, video view) using programming

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

i want to visible or invisible the XML file items...i am parsing data using XML and and putting values in image view, video view and text view..the thing i want to show in my application is that if there is only "text" available in xml item then it hide the other itemViews and if text + image is available then show image with text and hide the rest..

```
This is my XML FILE DATA
 <items>
    <item id="1">
   <MessageID>1</MessageID>
   <PublishDateTime>xxxxxxxx</PublishDateTime>
   <MessageText>xxxxxxxxx</MessageText>
   <MediaURL></MediaURL>
   <MediaMIMEType></MediaMIMEType>
 <MediaSize>0</MediaSize>
 <Likes>10</Likes>
 <Shares>5</Shares>
 <PublishedBy>xxxxxxxxxxxx</PublishedBy>
</item>
<item id="2">
<MessageID>2</MessageID>
<PublishDateTime>xxxxxxx</PublishDateTime>
<MessageText>xxxxxxxx xxx  x<br>xxxxxx.</br>xxxxxxx</MessageText>
<MediaURL>https://www.xxxx.org/wp-content/xxx/xxx/xx/xxxxx.jpg</MediaURL>
<MediaMIMEType>image/jpeg</MediaMIMEType>
<MediaSize>111649</MediaSize>
<Likes>100</Likes>
<Shares>95</Shares>
<PublishedBy>xxxx xxxxx xxxxx</PublishedBy>
</item>
<item id="3">
 <MessageID>3</MessageID>
 <PublishDateTime>xxxxxxxx</PublishDateTime>
 <MessageText>xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xx https://www.xxxxxxx.org/</MessageText>
 <MediaURL>https://xxxxxxx xxxxx.org/wp-content/xxxx/xxxx/xx/xxxxx.jpg</MediaURL>
 <MediaMIMEType>image/jpeg</MediaMIMEType>
 <MediaSize>76602</MediaSize>
 <Likes>64</Likes>
 <Shares>42</Shares>
 <PublishedByxxxxxxxxxxxx</PublishedBy>
 </item>
 <item id="4">
 <MessageID>4</MessageID>
 <PublishDateTime>1482227547</PublishDateTime>
 <MessageText></MessageText>
 <MediaURL>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxx</MediaURL>
 <MediaMIMEType>video/mpeg</MediaMIMEType>
 <MediaSize></MediaSize>
 <Likes>6100</Likes>
 <Shares>550</Shares>
 <PublishedBy>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</PublishedBy>
 </item>
 <item id="5">
 <MessageID>5</MessageID>
 <PublishDateTime>xxxxxxxx</PublishDateTime>
 <MessageText>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xx x x xxxxx xxxx</MessageText>
 <MediaURL></MediaURL>
 <MediaMIMEType></MediaMIMEType>
 <MediaSize></MediaSize>
 <Likes></Likes>
 <Shares></Shares>
 <PublishedBy>xxxxxxxx</PublishedBy>
 </item>
 <item id="6">
 <MessageID>6</MessageID>
 <PublishDateTime>xxxxxxxx</PublishDateTime>
 <MessageText></MessageText>
 <MediaURL>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxx xx</MediaURL>
 <MediaMIMEType>video/mpeg</MediaMIMEType>
 <MediaSize></MediaSize>
 <Likes>10110</Likes>
 <Shares>8011</Shares>
 <PublishedBy>xxxxx xxxxxx</PublishedBy>
  </item>
  <item id="7">
  <MessageID>7</MessageID>
  <PublishDateTime>xxxxxx</PublishDateTime>
  <MessageText>xxx xxx xxx</MessageText>
  <MediaURL>https://xxxxxxxx.org/wp-content/uploads/media/xxxxxx.mp3</MediaURL>
  <MediaMIMEType>audio/mp3</MediaMIMEType>
  <MediaSize></MediaSize>
  <Likes></Likes>
  <Shares></Shares>
  <PublishedBy>xxxxxxxxxx</PublishedBy>
  </item>
  <item id="8">
  <MessageID>8</MessageID>
  <PublishDateTime>xxxx</PublishDateTime>
  <MessageText>xxxxxxxxxxxx x xxxxx xxxxx.<br>xxxxx.</br></MessageText>
  <MediaURL></MediaURL>
  <MediaMIMEType></MediaMIMEType>
  <MediaSize></MediaSize>
  <Likes></Likes>
  <Shares></Shares>
  <PublishedBy>xxxxxxxxxx &lt;tel:+xxxxxxxxxxx&gt;</PublishedBy>
  </item>
```

`ReadRss.java`

```
  public class ReadRss extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
     Context context;

String address="https://xxxxx xxxxx.org/xxxxxxx/feed/";

ProgressDialog progressDialog;
ArrayList<FeedItem> feedItems;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
VideoView videoView;
View view;
MyAdapter adapter;
MyAdapter.MyViewHolder myViewHolder;

   URL url;
   Uri uri;


public ReadRss(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    this.recyclerView=recyclerView;
    this.context = context;
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog.show();
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    adapter=new MyAdapter(context,feedItems);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new VerticalSpace(50));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
  //  videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    ProcessXml(Getdata());

    return null;
}

private void ProcessXml(Document data) {
    if (data != null) {
        feedItems=new ArrayList<>();
        Element root = data.getDocumentElement();
        //Node channel = root.getChildNodes().item(1);
        NodeList items = root.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
            Node cureentchild = items.item(i);
            if (cureentchild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {

                FeedItem item=new FeedItem();
                NodeList itemchilds = cureentchild.getChildNodes();

                for (int j = 0; j < itemchilds.getLength(); j++) {

                    Node cureent = itemchilds.item(j);
                    if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                        item.setTitle(cureent.getTextContent());
                    } else if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MessageText")) {
                        item.setDescription(cureent.getTextContent());
                    } else if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("PublishDateTime")) {
                        item.setPubDate(cureent.getTextContent());
                    } else if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                        item.setLink(cureent.getTextContent());
                    } else if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MediaURL")) {
                        item.setMediaURL(cureent.getTextContent());
                    } else if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MediaMIMEType")) {
                        item.setMediaType(cureent.getTextContent());
                    } else {
                        //Nothing here, ignore other occurances of XML childern
                    }
                }

                Log.e("MediaType: ",item.getMediaType());
                Log.e("Media URL",item.getMediaURL());
                Log.e("Message text",item.getDescription());


                switch (item.getMediaType())
                   {

                       case "image/jpeg":

                           if(item.getDescription().isEmpty()){

                               Log.e("Message Text Empty","Only Media is Present");
                                    myViewHolder.Thumbnail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                               myViewHolder.Description.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                   myViewHolder.Thumbnail.getParent()).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                           }
                           if(item.getMediaURL().isEmpty()){
                               myViewHolder.Description.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                               myViewHolder.Thumbnail.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                           }

                           break;
                       case "video/mpeg":

                           break;
                       default:

                   }
                feedItems.add(item);
            }

        }
    }
}



public Document Getdata() {
    try {
        url = new URL(address);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        return xmlDoc;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
       }
    }
}

custum_row_news_item.xml

 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/cv"
app:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
app:cardElevation="4dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thumb_img"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumb_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/test"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/date_text"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp" />

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_above="@+id/title_text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#90f79a20"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_above="@+id/description_text"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

      </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

MyAdapter.java

```
    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
ArrayList<FeedItem> feedItems;
Context context;
ReadRss readRss;
int USER=0,IMAGE=1;
public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FeedItem> feedItems){
    this.feedItems=feedItems;
    this.context=context;
}
@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return feedItems.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
   /* if(feedItems.get(position) instanceof String ){
        ((TextView) feedItems.get(position));


    }*/
}

    public void bindDataToAdapter(){

}
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflator=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view= layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.custum_row_news_item,parent,false);
    View messageTextOnly=layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.messageonly,parent,false);
    MyViewHolder holder=new MyViewHolder(view);
    //MyViewHolder holder1=new MyViewHolder(messageTextOnly);
    return holder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    YoYo.with(Techniques.FadeInLeft).playOn(holder.cardView);
    final FeedItem current=feedItems.get(position);
    holder.Title.setText(current.getTitle());
    holder.Description.setText(current.getDescription());
    holder.Date.setText(current.getPubDate());
   if(current.getMediaURL().isEmpty()){
    holder.Thumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.butterfly);
   }else {
        Picasso.with(context).load(current.getMediaURL()).into(holder.Thumbnail);
    }
    //Picasso.with(context).load(current.getVideoUrl()).into((Target) holder.videoView);
   /* holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent( context,NewsDetail.class);
            intent.putExtra("Link",current.getLink());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });*/

}


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView Title,Description,Date;
    ImageView Thumbnail;
    CardView cardView;
    VideoView videoView;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Title= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
        Description= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description_text);
        Date= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_text);
        Thumbnail= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumb_img);
        cardView= (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
       // videoView=(VideoView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        }
     }
 }
```

MainActivity.java

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolBar;
private Menu menu;

ProgressBar mnuProgressBar;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
VideoView videoView;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolBar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolBar);
    toolBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    mnuProgressBar= (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
   // videoView=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    ReadRss readRss=new ReadRss(this,recyclerView);
    readRss.execute();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.menu=menu;
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    }
```

FeedItem.java

```
public class FeedItem {
String title;
String link;
String description;
String pubDate;
String mediaUrl;
String mediaType;
String vtViewType;

public String getMediaURL() { return mediaUrl;     }

public void setMediaURL(String mediaUrl) { this.mediaUrl = mediaUrl; }

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getLink() {
    return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getPubDate() {
    return pubDate;
}

public void setPubDate(String pubDate) {
    this.pubDate = pubDate;
}

public String getMediaType() {
    return mediaType;
}

public void setMediaType(String mediaType) {
    this.mediaType = mediaType;
}

public String getViewType() {
    return vtViewType;
}

public void setViewType(String viewType) {
    this.vtViewType = viewType;
    }
 }
```

All my links in xml file is working fine..please check the code and give me solution to how to Visible or Invisible the items and show in my activity...thanx in advace

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set visibility to your views conditionally. For instance if value of a certain text view is not null set its visibility to visible else gone/invisible. setvisiblity is the property you need.

Comment: You can use it as 
if(textviewvalue != null) { 
yourtextviewid.setVisiblity(View. VISIBLE)
} 
else {
yourtextviewid.setVisiblity(View. GONE)
}

Comment: can you please tell me where i should use this condition .in _ReadRss_ class or in _MyAdapter_ Class